# Wireless does not detect network on an Acer 5750 with a Broadcom 43227

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop Acer 5750. It detects wireless card and also lot of networks, but the problem is that it does not detect wireless network which is detected with my phone and another laptop (Has WinXP sp2 OS).

lspci|grep Network gives me only one line:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43227 802.11b/g/n
```

What could be a problem ?

Comment: Is the network a hidden network?

Comment: No, It is shown in the list of detected networks on my laptop with XP and also on my mobile phone... 
I also tried to 'Connect to a hidden wireless network' and entered network name, but with no results.

Comment: what security are you using? WPA, WEP,WPA2?

Comment: I tried all, but all of them requires to enter password so I can click Connect buton. But this network does not need password. So I choosed 'None'.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of your other devices (XP or mobile phone) to check which channel the router is using.

If it is 12 or 13 reduce this number and check networks again - it should work.